# setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition with redux connect immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux, warnings, immutability

I face a warning setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition.

I have found out that the problem is cause by immutable filter in the redux container. The warning stop once I remove `.filter(() => {})`. I would like to know why it happens. And what should I do if I need that filter. thanks.

p.s. This warning happens when hot module reloaded

The problem statement is shows below

```
export default connect(
  (state, ownProps) => {
    const someId = ownProps.someId;
    const someMap = state
      .getIn(['level1', 'someMap'])
      .filter(some => some.get('id') === someId); <-----this is the problem statement

    return ({
      someMap,
    });
  },

)(MyComponent);
```

I have tried to modify MyComponent to see what happen. Finally, the problem happen even I change MyComponent to below

```
function MyComponent() {
     return (<div>testing</div>)
}
```

Comment: Can you show, the code where you are using `someMap` ? like `this.props.someMap` ....

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Comment: I tested it locally and i m not getting any error.  The error is supposed to come only if the state is mutated. It is definitely not from the code snippet given above! Pls check this, https://gist.github.com/anupvarghese/65ee5dc9422622b183e34cb0bf179768

Comment: thx at all, I have just fixed this problem by implement the logic of areStatePropsEqual in redux-connect. Sounds like the filter() will create a new instance of map. It affects the rerender process in connect. I think it is something just like what componentShouldUpdate() do....